when trying my flutter app on real phone..my server doesn't get any requests
first I was trying my app on virtual emulator and every thing worked fine and the server at the backend received the requests ..but I wanna test on real phone but unfortunately the server doesn't receive any requests
I think I need to change my URL which was used for virtual emulator
http://10.0.2.2
but change it to what ? i tired to change it to my pc ip address 192.168.1.2 but still doesn't work
thanks in advance

Try using the same network connection in your real device that the system uses.

Possible that you are using Http only and Android is blocking an HTTP request
You can get more ideas from this blog
Please add the below code in your manifest file both
main-AndroidManifest
 <application
        android:label="Test"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

debug-AndroidManifest
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />

